# How do I install TortoiseHG/Mercurial Plugin in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, mercurial, tortoisehg, mercurialeclipse

Yesterday i downloaded new eclipse indigo. I had problem with java (no wirtual machine....), so i added new patch to java location.  However i instaled mercurial plugin from http://mercurialeclipse.eclipselabs.org.codespot.com/hg.wiki/update_site/stable and it doesnt work so well, and afterward when I open Eclipse its says "Problem Occured" and shows:

```
checking encoding (cp1250)... checking Python lib (E:\Programy\TortoiseHg\library.zip)...
checking installed modules (E:\Programy\TortoiseHg\library.zip\mercurial)...
checking templates (E:\Programy\TortoiseHg\templates)...
checking commit editor... Can't find editor 'notepad' in PATH (specify a commit editor in your configuration file)
checking username... no username found, using 'lolek@lolownia' instead
1 problems detected, please check your install!.
Command line: hg -y debuginstall"
```

Comment: You look new around here, so if any of the answers you get below help you please log back in and check the "accept" answer.  That prevents other folks looking for unanswered questions from coming back to this question again and again.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is right in that output.  It's saying you have to problems, one fatal and one not:

> checking commit editor... Can't find editor 'notepad' in PATH (specify
>   a commit editor in your configuration file) checking username...

When you do a commit Mercurial needs to launch a text editor.  By default on windows it launches `notepad` but the check isn't finding `notepad` in your path.  Find where youre `notepad.exe` is and make sure it's on your system path.  Here's the first google hit for that; I haven't done it in 15 years: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

> no username found, using 'lolek@lolownia' instead

You've not set a username for your commits, so they'll all show up as `lolek@lolownia` if that's a string you're happy with sharing with the world you're great, otherwise follow these instructions:

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/QuickStart#Setting_a_username